# An error has occurred.Type 'my api name controller' does not have a default constructorSystem.ArgumentException at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ninject.web.mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to create an mvc project with `angular`.so i create an `api controller` as you can see here :

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class TopicsController : ApiController
    {
        private IMessageBoardRepository _repo;
        public TopicsController(IMessageBoardRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Topic> Get(bool includeReplies = false)
        {
            IQueryable<Topic> results;

            if (includeReplies == true)
            {
                results = _repo.GetTopicsIncludingReplies();
            }
            else
            {
                results = _repo.GetTopics();
            }

            var topics = results.OrderByDescending(t => t.Created)
                                .Take(25)
                                .ToList();

            return topics;
        }

        // I didn't show this, but this is common
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id, bool includeReplies = false)
        {
            IQueryable<Topic> results;

            if (includeReplies == true)
            {
                results = _repo.GetTopicsIncludingReplies();
            }
            else
            {
                results = _repo.GetTopics();
            }

            var topic = results.Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (topic != null) return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, topic);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
}
}
```

I am using `ninject 3.2.1.0` to bind my interface to its repository .

```
   private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<MessageBoardContext>().To<MessageBoardContext>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IMessageBoardRepository>().To<MessageBoardRepository>().InRequestScope();
        }
```

But when i call this api with this url :`http://localhost:53005/api/v1/topics`
i got this error :

```
    An error has occurred.Type 'MvcApplication3.Controllers.TopicsController' does not have a default constructorSystem.ArgumentException   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

Comment: I think the ninject can't inject the repository into api

Comment: Did you set the DependencyResolver? http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api

Comment: @MarkBrackett no i didn't

Comment: In similar project that i don't use api controller i don't add any dependency resolver

Comment: @MarkBrackett is right. By default Mvc- and ApiController must have a parameterless constructor. When using a dependency injection framework like ninject you need to set the dependency resolver so ninject will create the controllers for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i should install `WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject` nuget and add this resolver to the `ninjectwebcommen` file as you can see here :

```
   private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
       new NinjectResolver(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
```